# Perl Print if regex match A and not regex match B

Tags: regex, perl, logic

I want to print a line of a file if it contains string A and it doesnt contain string B (also splitting into newlines at each colon). What is the proper syntax?  Here is what I tried ( **I want it print lines containing "bash" but to not print lines containing numbers**):

```
my $file = passwdtest;
open(FH, "$file"); 
foreach (<FH>) { 
print join("\n", split(/:/, "$_")) if ($_ =~ /bash/ and $_ != /\d+/);
};

close FH;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $_ != /\d+/
```

is short for

```
 $_ != ($_ =~ /\d+/)
```

Instead of `!=` you need `!~`

```
if ($_ =~ /bash/ and $_ !~ /\d+/);
```

Comment: Jeez, how dumb of me!  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that just:

```
if (/bash/ && ! /\d+/)
```